# Python: modify existing key-value pair and raising exception if key does not exist

Tags: python

I'd like to only change the value of a key in a dictionary if it already exists.

I could do this with the following function but am wondering if there is a more concise way of doing this.

```
def modify_existing_key_value(d, key, new_value):
    if key in d:
        d[key] = new_value
    else:
        raise KeyError(k)
```

The use case is to inadvertently avoid creating new key-value pairs in the dictionary.

Comment: If the calling code is going to have to check for an exception anyway (with a try-except block), why use a harder to read function that is essentially the same as the original if-statement (`if key in d`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try to access the element using the key, if it's there, nothing happens, and so the execution proceeds to the next instruction which resets the value, otherwise `KeyError` exception will be raised, as you want it:

```
def modify_existing_key_value(d, key, new_value):
    d[key] # We don't need the old value, just checking the key
    d[key] = new_value
```

The whole purpose of the first line of the function:

```
d[key]
```

is to raise `KeyError` exception if the dictionary doesn't contain the key.

Using d[key] to raise `KeyError` exception, a one-liner could be:

```
d[key] = new_value if key in d else d[key]
```

Comment: Why not just `d[key]` instead of binding it to a variable, seeing as you won't need it anyway?

Comment: It seems like I was the only one who actually read the question, still somebody downvoted me...

Comment: Just to make it more readable. But it's true, it's not necessary

Comment: to be honest I like OP's implementation better its more clear that he expects the key to exist ... I like verbosity (all the same +1)

Comment: OK, but Advait wanted something concise :)

Comment: I removed the unnecessary variable old_value, left the comment

Comment: It would be useful to mention that purpose of the first line of the function is to raise an exception if the key is not already in the dictionary.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a one-liner but I guess this is pretty close. How about:

    d[key] = new_value if key in d else d[key]

Comment: OK, it's a one-liner, but it's in fact more characters, so it's hard to say it's more concise :)

Comment: I know it's the same in the OP, but what is an `exiting_value`? I'm sure `existing_value` is meant, right?

Comment: @WesleyBaugh The only 'exiting_value' I can find on this page is the one in your comment

Comment: @piokuc Try `ctrl + f` ;) Also see: `def modify_exiting_key_value(...`